# how i can transform date format in "dd-MM-yyyy" i'm getting this in this format "yyyy-MM-dd" in NestJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

how i can transform date format in "dd-MM-yyyy" i'm getting this in this format "yyyy-MM-dd"
here is code in my entity

```
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty({ example: '1999-12-12', nullable: true })
  @Column({ type: 'date', nullable: true })
  birthDate?: Date;
```

im trying to transform in this format "dd-MM-yyyy"

Comment: _"im trying..."_ - I don't see any attempts in the question to solve this on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toLocaleDateString` with the wanted locale in argument will help you.

```
  transformDate(date: string): string {
    const options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
    return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

Create method in any service you want

```js
transformDate(date: string): string {
    const dateObject = new Date(date);
    return dateObject.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
      day: '2-digit',
      month: '2-digit',
      year: 'numeric',
    });
}
```

example of using:

```js
const date = '2022-12-28';
console.log(this.dateService.transformDate(date));
```